# WebRTC Call Audio - Quiet, Muffled and Drops

Tags: electron, webrtc, voip, chromium, freeswitch

I'm currently experiencing an intermittent issue with some VOIP WebRTC voice calls.

The symptom is that the outbound audio can sometimes fade in and out and sounds extremely muffled or even disappears momentarily.  The 2 audio files reference here show examples or a snippet from a good call and then a bad call, both very close together.  The audio is captured server side.

Good quality call - https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio-samples-mlcl/Good.mp3
Poor quality call - https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/audio-samples-mlcl/Poor.mp3

The tech stack is comprised of…

Electron application running on Mac/Windows
Electron wraps Chromium v66
WebRTC used within Chromium
OPUS codec used from client to server.
Wired network connection (stats show no packet loss and Jitter, RTT and delay are all very low)
SRTP used for media between client and TURN server (Coturn)
Cotur
Janus WebRTC Gateway
Freeswitch

These are using high-quality headsets and have been tested with various different manufacturers connecting to the Mac/Windows using USB.

Any ideas/help would be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a result of auto gain control. Try disabling it by passing autoGainControl: false to getUserMedia. In Chrome/electron googAutoGainControl and googAutoGainControl2 might still work.

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks for the response. I know we've tried, but I'll double check we've covered all the bases with the different variable names and we'll restest.

Comment: I have also find a chromium bug report which twilio submitted at the end of 2015 with some audio samples, which looks the same as our problem. It was left unsolved. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5137

Comment: Hi Philipp, I am also having this issue (see the stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542888/why-is-webrtc-dropping-audio/63543115)). I also have tried disabling autogaincrontrol, to no avail. Is there any other things that could cause this?