# Why Is WebRTC Dropping Audio

Tags: node.js, audio, webrtc, getusermedia

I am making a video conferencing app where audio is very important. I just overcame a major hurdle (took me about 2 weeks out of a 2 and a half weeks of working on it), switching audio devices, but now when I go to test it on 2 computers and turn up my microphone the audio goes quiet. I then turned up the mic input, which worked for about the same amount of time before the volume dropped. I even tried setting `autoGainControl` to `false`, but that didn't seem to do anything. Is there an easy way to do this?

---

I have tried: `noiseSuppression: false`, (obviously `autoGainControl`), `echoCancellation: false`, `channelCount: 2`, `latency: 0`, all of which did not work. Here is the current code for `getUserMedia`:

```js
                audio: {
                    echoCancellation: echoCancellationMASTER,
                    noiseSuppression: noiseSuppressionMASTER,
                    latency: 0,
                    sampleRate: 48000,
                    sampleSize: 24,
                    autoGainControl: false
                    /*autoGainControl: false,
                    channelCount: 2,
                    latency: 0,
                    volume: 3.0*/
                }
```

**Note that the commented out code is what I have also tried, but am not currently using.**

[Click here for the github code](https://github.com/divinelemon/videoChat)

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, go to `chrome://webrtc-internals` to ensure your constraints are getting applied correctly, in the way that you expect them to be.

Next, use a set of headphones on each to eliminate the possibility of feedback.  This will help confirm the problem, which I suspect is some echo cancellation algorithm somewhere.  Once you've confirmed that's the case...

Even though you set `echoCancellation` to `false`, and `noiseSuppression` to `false`, *many* devices still have their own "enhancements" for feedback reduction.  I suspect this is what you're hearing.

If this is the case, then there really isn't anything you can do about it as a web developer.  It's at a whole different layer apart from the browser.  I often see this problem with Lenovo's Realtek drivers when using the microphone as a "communications" device, but have had the same issue on other computers.

Comment: I use headphones, and haven't had any issues with feedback. However, I *am* using a Windows Lenovo with an external mic (the [hypemic](https://apogeedigital.com/products/hypemic)), do you think that the driver/external mic is the issue? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @divinelemon Oh, given the feature list of that microphone, I'd definitely be checking to see what it's doing to your levels.  Switch mics and see what happens.

Comment: I switched mics (to my default mic) and the default mic is very loud, and doesn't drop the audio. Could it be something with the hypemic?

Comment: @divinelemon Yes.

Comment: I actually tested it with another mic that plugs in to a box, called the Focusrite, which is very loud and uses a manual potentiometer to adjust the sound, but the sound is still dropping in volum whenever someone joins. I also have a Decibel Meter on the site that displays the input volume of the mic, and when I play for it without anyone on the site, the meter is almost at full, but when someone joins the meeting the meter goes below the half mark without me even touching anything, which is leading me to believe that it is something to do with WebRTC. Any ideas?

Comment: @divinelemon I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've shown here, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220331/discussion-between-divinelemon-and-brad).

Comment: see the code [here](https://github.com/divinelemon/videoChat)